# OrderedStreamElementQueue - potential deadlock

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-flink

It seems that I am getting into a deadlock when using an AsyncFunc in ordered mode.

I have been able to reproduced this bug as following:

```java
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.AsyncDataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.async.AsyncFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.async.collector.AsyncCollector;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class AsyncTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        DataStream<Integer> source = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7));

        AsyncDataStream.orderedWait(source,
                new AsyncFunction<Integer, String>(){
                    @Override
                    public void asyncInvoke(Integer integer, AsyncCollector<String> asyncCollector) throws Exception {
                           AsyncTest.getFuture(integer).whenComplete((t,m) -> {
                               if (m==null){
                                   asyncCollector.collect(Collections.singleton(t));
                                   return;
                               }
                               asyncCollector.collect(m);
                           });
                    }
                }, 20000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,5)
                .returns(String.class)
                .print();
        env.execute("unit-test");
    }

    static CompletableFuture<String> getFuture(Integer input) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            if (input == 7){
                System.out.println("Returning");
                return "ok";
            }
            System.out.println("Waking up");
            throw new RuntimeException("test");
        },new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10));
    }
}
```

I think that this deadlock could come from the fact that the underlying **ArrayQueue** of **OrderedStreamElementQueue** is first getting filled with incomplete futures.

When the **Emitter** tries to peek from this queue, as no future has completed, the Emitter pauses its execution.

When the futures complete, they complete exceptionally and hence do not trigger **onCompleteHandler** method that should have called signalAll on **headIsCompleted** (and hence wake up the Emitter thread)

At the same time, as the queue is full, any call to **tryPut** of **OrderedStreamElement** return false, and hence no **StreamElementQueueEntry** can be chain with the call to **onCompleteHandler**.

And so, it seems that the Emitter thread cannot be waken up.

This is just my guess. Maybe I am getting it wrong. But when I run the code above locally, the execution never ends.

Is there any way to overcome this problem except by increasing the capacity of the queue and or the parallelism of the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The problem was that the `StreamElementQueueEntry` did not react to exceptional completions of its future. Therefore, whenever a timeout or another exception occurred, the `StreamElementQueueEntry` was not properly set to completed and the `Emitter` was not notified about newly completed entries.

The problem has been fixed with [FLINK-6435](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-6435) which has already been merged to the Flink master.